# Laravel : Eloquent highest number in column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `users` table with `User` model, where every user have credit.

Suppose i have 3 users

User 1 have `500`

User 2 have `300`

User 3 have `200`

How can i get all of these users for ranking, That user 1 have `500` credit, user 2 have `300` and user 3 have `200` !

I am not coming up with any logic .

Comment: `User::orderby('credit' , 'DESC')->get();` this will give you all users ordered by credit points, then you can use a counter for ranking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$user=User::all();
$user->sortBy('columnName')->first():
```

This Could solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
User::all()->sortBy('columnName', 'DESC')->first();
```

That should do as it reads. Select the user with the highest column name value.

Answer (score 0):

`User::all()->sortBy('columnName')->first();` will give you the lowest. Use 
`User::all()->sortBy('columnName', 'desc')->first():` to get the highest. If you want them all in order, replace `first()` with `get()`.

Comment: The following error comes up : `asort() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given`

Comment: did you replace columnName with the actual name of the column?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all users, sorted by `credit` in descending order:

```
User::orderBy('credit', 'DESC')->get();
```

This will give you the user with the highest value of `credit`:

```
User::orderBy('credit', 'DESC')->first();
```

Comment: How can i get for the present day ! For reporting !